# Sitecore 8.1- Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository, Sitecore.Analytics

Tags: sitecore

I'm using sitecore 8.1, .net mvc 4.5.2. The below error is shown when I access to the site.

Here is my setting at sitecode.analytics.config:

```
<contactRepository type="Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository, Sitecore.Analytics" singleInstance="true" />
```

Is there anything missing? how can I bypass the error?

Thanks

**Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository, Sitecore.Analytics (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).**

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository, Sitecore.Analytics (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Exception: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository, Sitecore.Analytics (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +108
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +230
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +41
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +100
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +451
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +91
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +81
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +82
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +416
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +198
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +451
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, Boolean assert) +38
   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeAutomation.Process(PipelineArgs args) +50
   (Object , Object[] ) +56
   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters) +36
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +365
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +158
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +165
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +498
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository, Sitecore.Analytics (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947444
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Comment: Can you please provide setting of your analytics config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to create a new sitecore 8.1 instance and then copy and paste the config and dll (starts with "Sitecode.Analystics") into the project. It works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Sitecore.Analytics.Data` dll file is not in your `bin` folder.

Make sure that all the Sitecore dll files are inside your website `bin` folder including `Sitecore.Analytics.Data`.

Comment: I could not find the file Sitecore.Analytics.Data.dll. The type "Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository" should be included in Sitecore.Analytics.dll as I can find it by Object browser

Comment: I have tried to create a new sitecore 8.1 instance and then copy and paste the config and dll (starts with "Sitecode.Analystics") into the project. It works